# Nested NSMutableDictionary efficiency and alternatives

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, performance

I need to store big amounts of nested strings and access all the data using some simple format (for example, 'my.data.object.path').

For example, if I've got the following structure:

```
- object1
- object2
-- nested1
-- nested2
--- nestednested1
```

I need to check, for example, if `object2.nested2.nestednested1` exists. Sometimes I also have to check whether `object2.nested2` and `object2` also exist.

Is it efficient to use nested NSMutableDictionary objects, or should I write some more efficient data storage model from scratch? Maybe there are ready-to-use 3rd-party solutions to this problem that you could suggest.

---

I was also thinking about storing all `my.variable.path` paths in a single `NSMutableDictionary`, so I can set variables simply doing `[storage setObject:object forKey:@"my.variable.path"]` and extract them by defining a custom method that split incoming path by dot and try to find the shortest chunk of path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would seriously consider using Core Data for this.

- It works great with large amounts of data.
- It is very memory efficient, even with very large amounts of data since it loads it as
  needed.
- You can access it exactly like in your example.
- It is built-in mature technology.

The main Apple document covering it is the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).
They also have [Core Data Tutorial for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) which is a little shorter and gets you started.

There are also lots of non-Apple tutorials available on the web.  One of my favorites is by Ran Wenderlich: [Core Data on iOS 5 Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started).  He also has other tutorials on Core Data linked from that article and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/core-data).

Comment: Could you provide an example or an external article that describes the usage of Core Data in a way you described it? I am very curious.

Comment: Sure, I'll add some more info to the question.  Core Data takes a little bit to learn, but it is VERY powerful and worth the effort.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I've already knew some things about Core Data, but I reckon the problem can be solved easier. See update to my question. By the way, I already use Core Data in other parts of my project.

Comment: If you are already using core data, then it becomes even easier and I recommend it even more.  Just create your new model based on the keypath's that you are showing above.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary are hash mapped, it is faster than Arrays.

And what level it is nested you can access it by `[dict valueForKeyPath.@"key1.key2...."]`

Upto 3 levels it fine, but if you are going beyond that then you can think of designing a Class structure to solve this problem.